# What is the current state of research on the representation of boolean functions using wavelets

Tags: boolean-algebra

The harmonic representation of boolean functions such as XOR or AND has been studied in different course note lectures that can be found on Google.

http://cs.mcgill.ca/~hatami/comp760-2011/

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/papers/analysis-survey.pdf

What is the state of research on the representation of boolean functions using wavelets?

Comment: Let's see what responses you get. It sounds like a good question for [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).